# Android layout overlay

Tags: android, android-layout

On Android devices, one can switch on a layout overlay in the developer options. That should be simple, but I don't understand what the red border actually shows.

This is a screen-shot of my layout:

[image: Android layout overlay]

and this is the corresponding XML:

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/keypad_4"
  android:text="4"
  android:layout_below ="@id/keypad_7"
  android:layout_alignLeft="@id/valueEntry"
  android:layout_width ="70dp"
  android:layout_height="60dp"
  android:layout_margin="0dp"
  android:padding="0dp" />
<Button
  android:id="@+id/keypad_5"
  android:text="5"
  android:layout_below ="@id/keypad_8"
  android:layout_toRightOf = "@id/keypad_4"
  android:layout_width ="70dp"
  android:layout_height="60dp"
  android:layout_margin="0dp"
  android:padding="0dp" />
```

To my understanding, the blue corners indicate the View's width and height, while the red border should show the actual content after padding has been applied.

Now, why is the red border still inset even though padding is zero? Does the Button class ignore the padding and apply its own fixed value?

Comment: Probably your container layout sets a padding?

Comment: You have to show us the entire xml.

Comment: You can think it like this. The red border is your view and the outer border blue is your parent. The lines are boundary between views.

Comment: The Button ignores any padding. Just found out that when setting `android:background="@null"`, the padding is gone, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964748/android-button-with-no-padding), but also the button graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: apparently my understanding of the layout overlay is correct, but a Button takes its padding from the background drawable. In this case (Holo theme), this is a 9-patch with built-in padding. The value in the XML is ignored.